# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    // do all the fancy stripe stuff...
    event.preventDefault();
    setProcessing(true);

    const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
            card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
        }
    }).then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
        // paymentIntent = payment confirmation

        db
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user?.uid)
          .collection('orders')
          .doc(paymentIntent.id)
          .set({
              basket: basket,
              amount: paymentIntent.amount,
              created: paymentIntent.created
          })

        setSucceeded(true);
        setError(null)
        setProcessing(false)

        dispatch({
            type: 'EMPTY_BASKET'
        })

        history('/orders',{replace : true})
    })

}
```

Getting this error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`
I think due to this error I am not able to process payments using stripe
when I click on Buy Now button it shows processing forever and a blank window pops us and goes. I am using Stripe to accept payments.

Comment: just console `paymentIntent` first with in then, and see there is id exist or not.

Comment: do not use object destructuring in the "then" callback and add a null checking for the argument in the callbakc

Comment: @AndreiBelokopytov what's wrong with object destructuring?

Comment: in this case it breaks your program immediately if argument is null or undefined so  you need to implement null checking first

Comment: @MohitSharma its undefined

Comment: @GayatriBarhate its mean you are doing something wrong in calling `confirmCardPayment` please check doc here `https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/payment_method`

Comment: @MohitSharma Can you please tell what's wrong the confirmCardPayment. I can't figure it out .

Comment: @AndreiBelokopytov Can you please give me the right code .

Comment: @GayatriBarhate just remove this `({ paymentIntent })` to `(response)`, console response and see what you get. and provide object to communitiy so they can help you more which contain either `paymentIntent or error`

Answer (score 1):

Do not use object destructuring in the "then" callback and add a null checking for the argument in the callback.

Something like this

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    // do all the fancy stripe stuff...
    event.preventDefault();
    setProcessing(true);

    const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
            card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
        }
    }).then((paymentInfo) => {
        // paymentIntent = payment confirmation
        
        if (!paymentInfo) {
          return;
        }
        const { paymentIntent } = paymentInfo;

        db
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user?.uid)
          .collection('orders')
          .doc(paymentIntent.id)
          .set({
              basket: basket,
              amount: paymentIntent.amount,
              created: paymentIntent.created
          })

        setSucceeded(true);
        setError(null)
        setProcessing(false)

        dispatch({
            type: 'EMPTY_BASKET'
        })

        history('/orders',{replace : true})
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the null & undefined value for id as well. Same as you did for uid.
Changes in code -

> .doc(paymentIntent?.id)

```js
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    // do all the fancy stripe stuff...
    event.preventDefault();
    setProcessing(true);

    const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
            card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
        }
    }).then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
        // paymentIntent = payment confirmation

        db
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user?.uid)
          .collection('orders')
          .doc(paymentIntent?.id)
          .set({
              basket: basket,
              amount: paymentIntent.amount,
              created: paymentIntent.created
          })

        setSucceeded(true);
        setError(null)
        setProcessing(false)

        dispatch({
            type: 'EMPTY_BASKET'
        })

        history('/orders',{replace : true})
    })

}
```